# Finding the intervals where $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x-2|}-x$ is monotonous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Given $$f(x)=\frac{1}{|x-2|}-x.$$ I am interested in finding the intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ in which the function is monotonically increasing or decreasing.

Usually I would take $f'(x)>0$ for the function to be monotonically increasing and then solve for $x$ and then find the interval. And for $f$ to be monotonically decreasing $f'(x)<0$ and then the same as mentioned.

However, the inclusion of the absolute value in the function is causing me some problems. How do I take its derivative? Do I have to break the function into parts and then find the intervals?

**EDIT:** For one part of the function $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x-2} -x \text{ if } x < 2$, the derivative $$f'(x) = \frac{1}{(x-2)^{2}}-1.$$ So $f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow 1= (x-2)^{2}$.

So the function is strictly increasing at $f'(x)>0 \Rightarrow 1>(x-2)^{2}$ and strictly decreasing at $f'(x)<0 \Rightarrow 1<(x-2)^{2}$. So $1>|x-2|$ and $1<|x-2|$ and hence the interval in which $f$ is increasing is $(1,3)$ and the interval in which it is decreasing is $(\infty,1) \cup (3,\infty)$.

I am not sure what to make of the other part though. I have taken the derivative of the function $f=\frac{1}{x-2}-x \text{ if }x > 2$ and found $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2}}-1.$$

So if I let $f'(x)=0$ then I get something like this $(x-2)^{2} \neq -1$. If $f'(x) > 0$ then I get $-1>(x-2)^{2}$. On the other hand if $f'(x)<0$ where $-1<(x-2)^{2}$. So how I proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, split the absolute value according to whether $x>2$ or $x<2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly right - you just break up the absolute value into parts:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{|x-2|}-x=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2-x}-x&\text{if }x<2\\\frac{1}{x-2}-x&\text{if }x>2\end{cases}$$

From here, you can proceed as normal with the derivative arguments - that is breaking up the intervals into pieces where the derivative is positive and negative.

Do notice that $f(x)$ is not defined at $x=2$.

**Edit to reflect updates:**

The first part of your edit looks good, though remember that we only care about the function when $x<2$, so we can conclude our original function decreases on $(-\infty,1)$ and increases on $(1,2)$.

For the second part, you are correct as well, it just seems you are not sure what conclusion to draw. First note that there is no real $x$ such that $-1>(x-2)^2$ because $(x-2)^2$ is never negative. This means there is no $x$ such that $f'(x)>0$. All this means is that the function in never increasing. Similarly, every real $x$ satisfies $-1<(x-2)^2$ which means $f'(x)<0$ for every real $x$, and so the function is always decreasing (a conclusion we could have drawn already since we knew it was never strictly increasing). So this function decreases on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Putting everything together, you get that the original function is decreasing on $(-\infty,1)\cup(2,\infty)$ and increasing on $(1,2)$. A graph of the original function can confirm this conclusion.

Comment: I have made an edit

Comment: @OGC I have as well :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Notice that
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} -\frac{1}{x-2}-x&x<2\\
\frac{1}{x-2}-x&x>2
\end{cases}$$